# User typed table javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I've been trying to make a table based on user inputs, however, I can't run the writeTable function of the cell id when the input field is exited. I assume it is a syntax error with the functions, but I cannot find a solution online.

JAVASCRIPT

```
<script>
    function writeTable(tableID) {
        var n = document.getElementById("tableID");
        document.getElementById("tableID").innerHTML = n;
    }
</script>
```

HTML

```
<!-- INPUT TABLE -->
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Angle (c)</th>
        <th>Voltage - Test 1</th>
        <th>Voltage - Test 2</th>
        <th>Voltage - Test 3</th>
        <th>Voltage - Test 4</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th> 0 </th>
        <th> <input id="00" onblur="writeTable(00)" type="text"> </th>
        <th> <input id="10" onblur="writeTable(10)" type="text"> </th>
        <th> <input id="20" onblur="writeTable(20)" type="text"> </th>
        <th> <input id="30" onblur="writeTable(30)" type="text"> </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th> π/12 </th>
        <th> <input id="01" onblur="writeTable(01)" type="text"> </th>
        <th> <input id="11" onblur="writeTable(11)" type="text"> </th>
        <th> <input id="21" onblur="writeTable(21)" type="text"> </th>
        <th> <input id="31" onblur="writeTable(31)" type="text"> </th>
    </tr>
</table>
<!-- DISPLAY TABLE -->
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Angle (c)</th>
        <th>Voltage - Test 1</th>
        <th>Voltage - Test 2</th>
        <th>Voltage - Test 3</th>
        <th>Voltage - Test 4</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th> 0 </th>
        <th id="00"></th>
        <th id="10"></th>
        <th id="20"></th>
        <th id="30"></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th> π/12 </th>
        <th id="01"> </th>
        <th id="11"></th>
        <th id="21"></th>
        <th id="31"></th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is Your Solution :

```
    <!-- INPUT TABLE -->
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Angle (c)</th>
            <th>Voltage - Test 1</th>
            <th>Voltage - Test 2</th>
            <th>Voltage - Test 3</th>
            <th>Voltage - Test 4</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th> 0 </th>
            <th> <input id="0" onblur="writeTable(00)" type="text"> </th>
            <th> <input id="10" onblur="writeTable(10)" type="text"> </th>
            <th> <input id="20" onblur="writeTable(20)" type="text"> </th>
            <th> <input id="30" onblur="writeTable(30)" type="text"> </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th> 12 </th>
            <th> <input id="1" onblur="writeTable(01)" type="text"> </th>
            <th> <input id="11" onblur="writeTable(11)" type="text"> </th>
            <th> <input id="21" onblur="writeTable(21)" type="text"> </th>
            <th> <input id="31" onblur="writeTable(31)" type="text"> </th>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <!-- DISPLAY TABLE -->
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Angle (c)</th>
            <th>Voltage - Test 1</th>
            <th>Voltage - Test 2</th>
            <th>Voltage - Test 3</th>
            <th>Voltage - Test 4</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th> 0 </th>
            <th id="t0"></th>
            <th id="t10"></th>
            <th id="t20"></th>
            <th id="t30"></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th> 12 </th>
            <th id="t1"> </th>
            <th id="t11"></th>
            <th id="t21"></th>
            <th id="t31"></th>
        </tr>
    </table>    

<script>
    function writeTable(tableID) {
        var n = document.getElementById(tableID);
        document.getElementById("t"+tableID).innerHTML = n.value;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, that works great. Just a quick question though, is the id combining with "t" just to make the output id different from the input?

Comment: Sorry i didnt get you?

Comment: I was asking what this line was for
    `document.getElementById("t"+tableID).innerHTML = n.value;`
but my question has now been answered by prasad

Answer (score 0):

Try this .you could change your html `onclick=writeTable('targetlementid',this)` .And dont use some id for both `input` and `td`.Because id is unique .so differentiate the `td` from input id .Just like  add `t` in before `td id="t00"`

```js
function writeTable(tableID,that) {
  document.getElementById('t'+tableID).innerHTML = that.value;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Angle (c)</th>
    <th>Voltage - Test 1</th>
    <th>Voltage - Test 2</th>
    <th>Voltage - Test 3</th>
    <th>Voltage - Test 4</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th> 0 </th>
    <th> <input id="00" onblur="writeTable('00',this)" type="text"> </th>
    <th> <input id="10" onblur="writeTable('10',this)" type="text"> </th>
    <th> <input id="20" onblur="writeTable('20',this)" type="text"> </th>
    <th> <input id="30" onblur="writeTable('30',this)" type="text"> </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th> π/12 </th>
    <th> <input id="01" onblur="writeTable('01',this)" type="text"> </th>
    <th> <input id="11" onblur="writeTable('11',this)" type="text"> </th>
    <th> <input id="21" onblur="writeTable('21',this)" type="text"> </th>
    <th> <input id="31" onblur="writeTable('31',this)" type="text"> </th>
  </tr>
</table>
<!-- DISPLAY TABLE -->
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Angle (c)</th>
    <th>Voltage - Test 1</th>
    <th>Voltage - Test 2</th>
    <th>Voltage - Test 3</th>
    <th>Voltage - Test 4</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th> 0 </th>
    <th id="t00"></th>
    <th id="t10"></th>
    <th id="t20"></th>
    <th id="t30"></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th> π/12 </th>
    <th id="t01"> </th>
    <th id="t11"></th>
    <th id="t21"></th>
    <th id="t31"></th>
  </tr>
</table>
```